# How do I get my EntitySetController to be visible to my route?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I created an EntitySetController that looks like this:

```
   public class OrdersController : EntitySetController<Order,Guid>
{
    private readonly PizzaCompanyEntities _context = Factories.DataFactory.GetPizzaContext();

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            _context.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

    public override IQueryable<Order> Get()
    {
        return _context.Orders;
    }

    protected override Order GetEntityByKey(Guid key)
    {
        var result = _context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(o => o.Id == key);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.NotFound);
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

In an existing MVC 4 web application.
I configure the route as follows:

```
public static class WebApiConfig
{
    public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
    {
        config.Routes.MapODataRoute("PizzaApi", "odata", GetImplicitEdm());
    }

    private static IEdmModel GetImplicitEdm()
    {
        var builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<Order>("Orders");
        builder.EntitySet<Pizza>("Pizzas");
        builder.EntitySet<Pizzas_To_Orders>("PizzasToOrders");
        builder.EntitySet<Size>("Sizes");
        builder.EntitySet<Status>("Statuses");
        builder.EntitySet<Pizzas_To_Toppings>("PizzasToToppings");

        return builder.GetEdmModel();
    }
}
```

And execute the configuration as follows:

```
    public class MvcApplication : System.Web.HttpApplication
{
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration);
        FilterConfig.RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
        BundleConfig.RegisterBundles(BundleTable.Bundles);
    }
}
```

But when I execute my route at `http://localhost:29064/odata/Orders` I am getting a 404 and a message "The controller for path /odata/Orders was not found or does not implement IController.

I cannot figure out what I am missing to get the route registered and the controller running.  I have done a similar application from scratch and have not had this trouble.

How do I get my OData route working?

Comment: Wow, talking about latency! Anyways. I think you are missing the config.EnableQuery() (assuming V3, for V4 its changed to AddODataQueryFilter()) call in your Register method of the WebApiConfig class.